# JAVA-EE/EJB Prime numbers 'lower or equal' and 'higher' then 'n' parameter

Tags: java, servlets, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-3.1

I got this kind of task in EJB/Servlets in Java EE: I have parameter, let's call it 'n' which I get from URL. In 'doGET' method I have to find first prime number lower or equal 'n' and in 'doPOST' I have to find first prime number higher than 'n'.

Also there is a thing - the searched prime numbers must fulfill the condition: 4k + 3 and this condition must be implemented in methods in stateless bean. Here is what I wrote:

```
@Stateless
public class NprimeBean implements NprimeRemote {

    @Override
    public int prime(int n) {
        boolean isCorrectNumber = checkIfPrime(n) && checkIsMatching(n);
        return n;
    }

    boolean checkIfPrime(int n){
        //check if n is a multiple of 2
        if (n%2==0) return false;
        //if not, then just check the odds
        for(int i=3;i*i<=n;i+=2) {
            if(n%i==0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    boolean checkIsMatching(int n){
        return (n - 3) % 4 == 0;
    }

}
```

So basicly my question is how to do such a task when I have gone so far?? 
Servlet code so far: http://wklejto.pl/308087

Comment: which part of the task is unclear to you?